# deleting "checked" records via populated checkboxes in PHP

Tags: php

Hi I'm a newbie to PHP and please help me understand where I've gone wrong. Below is an extraction of the lengthy code I have where I'm trying to get SQL database values to a table with checkboxes adding in-front, allowing users to pick and delete the record they want. My issue is once a record is picked through the checkbox and hit delete, the record isn't getting deleted.

The `Validation bit` is what I have in the code to delete the checkbox picked values. `Populating checkboxes for each data row extracted from the database:` will tell you how I'm getting the checkboxes via the loop.

If the information provided isn't sufficient please highlight. Thank you.
**Validation bit :**

```
if(isset($_POST['deletez'])) 
  {
    foreach($_POST['deletez'] as $wec)
    {
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'regional_data');
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {die('The connection to the database could not be established.');}
    $rW = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE * FROM brands WHERE bname ='$wec'");
    } 
  }
```

**Populating checkboxes for each data row extracted from the database:**

```
while ($reK = mysqli_fetch_array($runBrands))
{
$wec = $reK['bname'];
    echo "<tr class='brndTab'>";
echo "<tr>" 
."<td><input type='submit' name='deleteR' id='deleteR' value='Delete.'></td>". 
"</tr>";    
echo "</table>";
    echo "<td class='brndTab'>".$reK["bname"]."</td>";
    echo "<td class='brndTab'>".$reK["bvariant"]."</td>";
    echo "<td class='brndTab1'>".$reK["bsku"]."</td>";
    echo "<td class='brndTa'><input type='checkbox' name='deletez[]' value='$wec'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you shouldn't connect to the db inside the loop, move the line $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'regional_data'); outside of the foreach loop. Otherwise you open a new connection for each entry. Next, you have an error in the mysql syntax, correct statement would be DELETE FROM brands WHERE bname ='$wec'". Because you want to delete the row, not the contents of the row. To put this together, modify your code like this:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'regional_data');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {die('The connection to the database could not be established.');}
foreach($_POST['deletez'] as $wec) {
    $rW = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM brands WHERE bname ='$wec'");
}
```